# pandas: print to csv dataframe with keys

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have dataframe df1 as:

```
df1.ix[1:3]
                df1             df2
                col1    col2    col1    col2    col3  
Date                                                             
2018-03-01      8.5     1.12    0.5     12      3.12  
2018-03-03      3.5     112     1.5     11      612
```

When I print to csv the dataframe as:

```
df1.to_csv(r'C:\z1.csv')
```

The `z1.csv` shows up as:

```
                 df1      df1       df2     df2     df2
                 col1     col2      col1    col2    col3    
        Date                        
        3/1/2018  8.5       1.12    0.5     12      3.12    
        3/3/2018  3.5       112     1.5     11      612
```

How do I make it print to `z1.csv` so that I get the following:

```
                df1             df2
                col1    col2    col1    col2    col3  
Date                                                             
2018-03-01      8.5     1.12    0.5     12      3.12  
2018-03-03      3.5     112     1.5     11      612
```

Edit: This dump to csv is for presentation purposes so for my case I don't care about reading problems into csv

Comment: You know this will make  reading the csv difficult.

Comment: Well for the presentation purpose you dont need csv. After dumping read it as `pd.read_csv('outd.csv',index_col=[0],header=[0,1])` So it prints well after reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your column index is a MultiIndex.  Don't know how to do this natively with pandas on it's own but I've been achieving what you are after with [xlsxwriter](https://readthedocs.org/projects/xlsxwriter/).

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('~/somepath/deathstarplans.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
my_pandas_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='top_secret')
writer.save()
```